# Prime React - DataTable - CSV Eexport fails in chrome but is working in IE

Tags: reactjs, export-to-csv, sharepoint-online, spfx, primereact

I am using Prime React library for implementing it's DataTable feature in an application built using SPFX with react for SharePoint Online - WebPart.

In local serve, the csv export feature is working in both IE & Chrome. but when the built files are deployed to Sharepoint site, csv export feature is failing in Chrome but is working fine in IE. Need a resolution for this.

i have raised the same concern in [primefaces/primereact library](https://github.com/primefaces/primereact/issues/1098) .

Issue seems to be related with the library.
looking for solutions or workarounds.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

I have also used  react-csv to export data it works inconsistently and it will take time to download the File if the data count is high.

If csv is not your concern better go with  xlsx npm package ,it works fine in all prime Browsers even after deploying in Site also it faster compared to  'react-csv'.

Let me know if you have any doubts.

Comment: Hi Prajeesh, Prime react is a library which has a component named DataTable with Export to CSV feature. react-csv is all together a diiferent library specifically for csv export feature. What I was looking forward to know is why when built files are deployed to the site, it is not working in chromebut in IE. Is there any workaround without using an alternate library for just csv-export?